# Draggable Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to implement this [vue draggable component](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) within my component.  My component works fine without the draggable component, but once draggable is added everything is blank.  I'm thinking that it is a configuration issue.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

The most recent error I'm getting is

> Invalid vnode type when creating vnode: undefined

```
<template>
<div :class="['image-select']">
  <draggable v-model="images">
    <div v-for="image in images"
         :class="['image-select-image']"
         :key="image.id">
        <input type="hidden"
             :name="fieldName()"
             :value="image.id">
      <img :src="imageUrl(image,size)" :alt="image.alt">
    </div>
  </draggable>
</div>
</template>

<script setup>
import {onBeforeMount, ref} from 'vue';
import api from "../modules/api";
import {draggable} from "vuedraggable";

const props = defineProps({
    size: {
        type: String,
        default: 'sm'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: 'images'
    },
    selectedValues: {
        type: Object,
        default: null
    }
});

const images = ref([]);

onBeforeMount(async () => {
    await Promise.all([
        setImages()
    ]);
});

function fieldName(){
    return props.name + '[images][]';
}

function imageUrl(image, size){
    return image.src.replace(/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/,'/'+size+'$1');
}

function setImages(){
 // load images from ids in selectedValues
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next#typical-use), you're supposed to import without curly braces `{}`

```js
import draggable from 'vuedraggable';
```

Based on how the vuedraggable component is exported, using the curly braces will make the import fail.

See this [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-waterfall-g6ntve?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: that you for responding, unfortunately removing the curly braces created more errors.
`[Vue warn]: Property "$scopedSlots" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.`
`[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function`
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'header')`
`[Vue warn]: Property "_sortable" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance`
`Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of watcher callback`
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'option')`

Comment: The new errors would've been supressed by the failed import.  Go ahead and post them because following the documentation and not having curly braces is 100% the correct import procedure.

Comment: By the way, vuedraggable when installed via `npm install vuedraggable` will install a version that is only compatible with Vue 2.  I'm going to guess that maybe this is the source of your additional errors.  To resolve, try `npm install vuedraggable@next` which will install the Vue 3 compatible version.

Comment: Thank you @yoduh I needed to use the different version.  One thing to note for anyone else I needed to specify `<template #item="{element}">`

Comment: @yoduh you should update answer with usefule comment :) but, thanks